# Mobile WiFi Sync Station

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I would like to connect to my home network from a distance out in a field.

If I bought something like an EnGenius outside wireless point and shot it out through all the trees and it was to go out over 1000ft, could I then use something like the [this](https://hakshop.myshopify.com/products/wifi-pineapple) and attach something like [this](https://hakshop.myshopify.com/collections/antennas/products/ant500-telescopic-antenna) to it, could that then be used as my mobile hotspot which could be used to connect to my home WiFi?

The idea is I'll be mobile and can't mount a WiFi access point as there is no power.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I do not know of a wifi access point that is battery powered that has a range of 1000ft. Anything this powerful will either need hard wired power, or a large battery that you will not be able to carry around in your pocket. When you are attempting to use wifi over long distances, you will need to trade off distance vs directionality. Also you will need higher signal strength, which is why there are no premade battery powered access points for this purpose.

There is only one option that I can think of that will work, however it will need some sort of power in the field. A good option for portable power is a deep cycle marine battery connected to an AC inverter like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001RNOHBC). you can put this on a hand dolly or something similar to make it easy to move. you could also put a solar panel and battery charger on the dolly as well if you wanted to get fancy, otherwise you would need to charge the battery at your house when you were not using it.

The first option for establishing a network connection is to use 2 directional wifi bridges, one on your house, and one in the field. These are directional and will need to be mounted 15-20 feet in the air to get max range. At your remote station in the field, you would have a wifi access point connected to your bridge, which is what your computer or other device would connect to. An example of the bridge would be [this](http://www.cyberguys.com/product-details/?productid=62258&rH=1725) and an example of the access point would be something like [this](http://www.cyberguys.com/product-details/?productid=43622&rH=1721).

If you do not need a connection to your houses network specifcally, but just an internet connection, you could use a cellular internet card, either directly connected to your computer, or to one of [these](http://www.cyberguys.com/product-details/?productid=78518&rH=1724). You will need cellular service and a cellular plan to use this option which may be more than you want to spend.